# How would you create a constructor for a struct containing a closure?

Tags: rust

How would I go about implementing a method that acts as a constructor for a struct that contains a closure?  I'm new to Rust, and what with closures being actively worked on I'm having a hard time finding a solution in the documentation.

```
struct A<'self> {
    fOne: &'self fn(),
}

impl<'self> A<'self> {
    fn new() {
        println!("Ideally this would return a struct of type A");
    }
}

fn run(f: &fn()) {
    f();
}

fn main() {
    let apples = 5;
    let example = A {
        fOne: || {
            println!("{} apples on the tree.", apples);
        },
    };
    A::new();

    run(example.fOne);
}
```

This is as far as I can get without running into a host of issues.  I can't seem to create a version of `A::new()` that accepts a closure as an argument, creates a struct of type `A` with that argument, and then returns the newly created struct.  Is there a way to do this, or if not, what don't I understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Closures are treated as a type of generic; it's common to use the type parameter name `F`:

```
struct A<F> {
    f_one: F,
}

impl<'a, F> A<F> {
    fn new(f: F) -> Self {
        A { f_one: f }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let apples = 5;
    let example = A::new(|| println!("{} apples on the tree.", apples));

    (example.f_one)(); // extra parens to disambiguate from calling a method
}
```

Often you will see a restriction on the type or `impl` block that restrict the generic to a specific type of closure:

```
struct A<F>
where
    F: Fn(),
{
    f_one: F,
}

impl<'a, F> A<F>
where
    F: Fn(),
{
    fn new(f: F) -> Self {
        A { f_one: f }
    }
}
```